# Change date format of field in DataView

Tags: asp.net, dataview

I have a date field in a DataView that I would like to format to display "MM/DD/YYYY".  The problem is I get this date from a service and I can't seem to format it in the Eval function where I set the field in my DataView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTransactionHistory" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTransactionDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("transactionDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I tried adding the String.Format("{mm/DD/yyyy}") to the Text property but that's not allowed.  I also tried the Pre_Render event of the DataView but I am not running into much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format is the second parameter of `Eval`.  The following should get you there:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTransactionDate" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Eval("transactionDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Notice that I changed the format string from `mm/DD/yyyy` to `MM/dd/yyyy`.

`MM` - Month

`mm` - Minute

`DD` - Not valid

`dd` - Day

---

**Edit:**

I assume your `transactionDate` may be a string.  In that case, use the following:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTransactionDate" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",DateTime.Parse(Eval("transactionDate").ToString())) %>'></asp:Label>
```

Above I have converted the `string` to a `DateTime` so that it can utilize the format.

Comment: Tried it and still got the old way as though I didn't format anything.  Ideas?

Comment: Is your `transactionDate` property a `DateTime` or a `string`?

Comment: Khan, it would appear that the date is returned as a string, for example: "2013-09-30"

Comment: @user2146538 I think your property may be a string.  Please see my edit.

Comment: Khan, I had the capital MM but I converted the string to a DateTime and it works now.  Thanks.  <asp:Label ID="lblTransactionDate" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("transactionDate"))) %>'></asp:Label>

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTransactionDate" runat="server" Text='<%#String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",Eval("transactionDate"))  %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Are you sure you used MM, not mm and dd not DD?